# How to Use Yarn to Install a Local Package Globally?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, yarnpkg, package.json

I have some Node.js CLI code in a folder. To install it globally, I usually `cd` into its directory and type `npm i -g .`

What is the equivalent to add a local package taht will work as a global CLI with yarn (`yarn global add .` returns an error)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

According to [#3256](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3256) and [#5199](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5199#issuecomment-378551130) on [yarnpkg/yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn), a method that works is:

```
yarn global add "file:$PWD"
```

This command assumes the $PWD environment is present, and the command is run from the location the local package is in. You may need to construct an absolute path some other way, if you are not running the command from the same location.

#3256 has some additional notes on how the `npm` and `yarn` global installs differ, in terms of the directories used to hold the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
# git-bash for Windows
yarn global add $PWD

# zsh, bash etc. for mac OS
yarn global add file:$PWD
```

By the way, I prefer use `yarn link` and `yarn link mySomeCliPackageName`

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5199#issuecomment-581700826